# Can Docker CLI, Podman and other similar tools have shared local storage for images?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, podman, buildah, docker-cli

I recently started using podman and realized that images pulled via docker doesn't become available for use to podman and vice-versa. For example:-

If I pull the image using docker CLI, as shown below

```
docker pull registry.access.redhat.com/ubi7-minimal
```

and If I want to use the same image with podman or buildah, turns out I cannot

```
[riprasad@localhost ~]$ podman inspect registry.access.redhat.com/ubi7-minimal
Error: error getting image "registry.access.redhat.com/ubi7-minimal": unable to find 'registry.access.redhat.com/ubi7-minimal' in local storage: no such image
```

I understand that this is because both podman and docker uses a different storage location and hence the image pulled down via docker doesn't becomes available for use with podman and vice-versa.

```
[riprasad@localhost ~]$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                                                                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
registry.access.redhat.com/ubi7-minimal                                                    latest              fc8736ea8c5b        5 weeks ago         81.5MB
```

```
[riprasad@localhost ~]$ podman images
REPOSITORY   TAG   IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE
```

Is there a way to mitigate this issue, and somehow make docker and podman work inter-changeably on the very same image, irrespective of whether it has been pulled down via docker or podman ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker and Podman do not share the same storage. They cannot, because Docker controls lock it to its storage within the daemon. On the other hand, Podman, Buildah, CRI-O, Skopeo can all share content between one another.

Podman and other tools can work with the docker-daemon storage indirectly, via the "docker-daemon" transport.

Something like this should work:

```bash
podman run docker-daemon:alpine echo hello
```

Note, that `podman` is pulling the image out of the docker daemon and is storing the image in its containers storage, and then running the container rather than using the Docker storage directly.

---

You can also do:

```bash
podman push myimage docker-daemon:myimage
```

To copy an image from containers/storage into the docker daemon (but not in the opposite direction as you probably would prefer).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @rhatdan's post

`podman run docker://alpine echo hello`

This worked for me.

For more details: [Here->](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/7-transports-features)